# Rhapsody (windows 7 version) for java , java samples project compiles, but run closes program immediately

Tags: java, rhapsody

Rhapsody (windows 7 version) for java , java samples Dishwasher, project compiles, but run closes program immediately
I am using rhapsody 8.4 but happens with other versions as well, with or without instrumentation
Do not have this problem with rhapsody for C++

Comment: Make certain you have installed a supported version of Java. Do NOT trust instructions that include the phrase "or more recent". More recent major release versions of Java have introduced breaking changes. They did not know this when they wrote those instructions. If it says "Java 8 or more recent", use Java 8. So, what version of Java are you currently using?

Comment: Using java 8_251  this is a known problem but don't see any solutions-thanks for your interest -Reuven